# force webbrowser control to not load images

Tags: c#, vb.net, browser, c#-to-vb.net

sorry for my poor english in advance.

i want to force webbrowser control to not load images for reducing traffic and loading document faster.

unfortunately using csWeb, gecko, webkit and... is out of question for me.

i already used httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse with setting explorer cookies in my project but in some cases i need browser to send rendered data.somehow the target site did some trick with java so the data need to be navigate by browser.

i'm not good with c or c#, i found some solutions but i couldn't understand

[Hidden Images of Webbrowser component to reduce memory usage](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/65772/Hidden-Images-of-Webbrowser-component-to-reduce-me)

and

[WebBrowser Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28VS.85%29.aspx)

i would be very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: this forum appears to have a solution:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?487419-2005-WebBrowser-control-is-it-possible-to-disable-image-loading

Comment: thanks a lot man. that's exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

my way is

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
RegKey.SetValue("Display Inline Images", "no");
```

for Gecko(baceuse gecko is  good for most purposes):

```
Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("xulrunner");
        GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_viewing_mixed"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["plugin.state.flash"] = 0;
        GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.disk.enable"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.memory.enable"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["permissions.default.image"] = 2;
```